How to split text file into multiple files in specific a pattern in terminal?
I have a large text file with FASTA sequence (basically text) of multiple genes. I would like to split the txt file into multiple files according to file name of genes.
The structure of the file looks like this:
file1.txt
>PDGFRB|ENST00000522466.1
TCAGTCATCCTTTCCCTCTCTAGCCCCCTACCCTATCCCCAAGCTGAAGTGCTAGTGGCT
GGTGGTGACTTCCCCAGACCTAAGCCAATCTCTCTCTACCAGTGTCATCCATCAACGTCT
CTGTGAACGCAGTGCAGACTGTGGTCCGCCAGGGTGAGAACATCACCCTCATGTGCATTG
TGATCGGGAATGAGGTGGTCAACTTCGAGTGGACATACCCCCGCAAAGAAGTAATGTGGG
GCCAGGCAGGGGTCGGAGGAGGGGCCAGGAACGGGTGGATATCTGGCTTGCAGGCTGATT
TCTCCCCGGCCCCTCCTGATTTGGGGGGCCTGCCCAACCTGTTGCTGCAGAGTGGGCGGC
TGGTGGAGCCGGTGACTGACTTCCTCTTGGATATGCCTTACCACATCCGCTCCATC
>DGAT2|ENST00000604935.5
AGAAAGGCCGGGCGCGGCGAGGCTGGGCGCTGGGCGGCTGCGGCGCGCGGTGCGCGGTGC
GTAGTCTGGAGCTATGGTGGTGGTGGCAGCCGCGCCGAACCCGGCCGACGGGACCCCTAA
AGTTCTGCTTCTGTCGGGGCAGCCCGCCTCCGCCGCCGGAGCCCCGGCCGGCCAGGCCCT
GCCGCTCATGGTGCCAGCCCAGAGAGGGGCCAGCCCGGAGGCAGCGAGCGGGGGGCTGCC
CCAGGCGCGCAAGCGACAGCGCCTCACGCACCTGAGCCCCGAGGAGAAGGCGCTGAGGAG
GTGGGCGAGGGGCCGGGGTCTGGGGCCAGATCTGAAGCCGGGACTAGGGACAGGGGCAGG

I want two files with the outputs as:
PDGFRB|ENST00000522466.1.txt
>PDGFRB|ENST00000522466.1
TCAGTCATCCTTTCCCTCTCTAGCCCCCTACCCTATCCCCAAGCTGAAGTGCTAGTGGCT
GGTGGTGACTTCCCCAGACCTAAGCCAATCTCTCTCTACCAGTGTCATCCATCAACGTCT
CTGTGAACGCAGTGCAGACTGTGGTCCGCCAGGGTGAGAACATCACCCTCATGTGCATTG
TGATCGGGAATGAGGTGGTCAACTTCGAGTGGACATACCCCCGCAAAGAAGTAATGTGGG
GCCAGGCAGGGGTCGGAGGAGGGGCCAGGAACGGGTGGATATCTGGCTTGCAGGCTGATT
TCTCCCCGGCCCCTCCTGATTTGGGGGGCCTGCCCAACCTGTTGCTGCAGAGTGGGCGGC
TGGTGGAGCCGGTGACTGACTTCCTCTTGGATATGCCTTACCACATCCGCTCCATC

and, DGAT2|ENST00000604935.5.txt
>DGAT2|ENST00000604935.5
AGAAAGGCCGGGCGCGGCGAGGCTGGGCGCTGGGCGGCTGCGGCGCGCGGTGCGCGGTGC
GTAGTCTGGAGCTATGGTGGTGGTGGCAGCCGCGCCGAACCCGGCCGACGGGACCCCTAA
AGTTCTGCTTCTGTCGGGGCAGCCCGCCTCCGCCGCCGGAGCCCCGGCCGGCCAGGCCCT
GCCGCTCATGGTGCCAGCCCAGAGAGGGGCCAGCCCGGAGGCAGCGAGCGGGGGGCTGCC
CCAGGCGCGCAAGCGACAGCGCCTCACGCACCTGAGCCCCGAGGAGAAGGCGCTGAGGAG
GTGGGCGAGGGGCCGGGGTCTGGGGCCAGATCTGAAGCCGGGACTAGGGACAGGGGCAGG

I tried this, it splits the files but does not save into separate files with gene names. It also gives the error 'ambiguous redirect'.
#!/bin/bash

IFS=">" read -r -d '' -a my_array < file1.txt

for element in "${my_array[@]}";
do
    gene_name=$(echo "$element" | awk '{print $1}')
    gene_name=$(echo "$gene_name" | cut -d $'\n' -f 1)
    echo "$gene_name"
    echo $"element" > $gene_name.txt
done


Always check your scripts in http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag you used - "NOTE: Do not ask a bash question until you have copy/pasted your script into http://shellcheck.net and fixed all of the issues it tells you about.".

I strongly recommend against using a | symbol in your file names.  There are many good reasons for sticking with the portable filename character set and restricting your names to use A-Za-z0-9._- Personally, I also recommend against uppercase letters, since they will burn you when you go go a case-insensitive filesystem. Putting a pipe symbol in your filenames is just asking for trouble.

$"element"  should be "$element" ; with that fix your code works for me; and while not a problem in this case I'd opt to wrap the target file in double quotes, ie, "$gene_name.txt" just to be safe; invoking 4 subshells for each pass through the loop isn't very efficient and while there are a few ways to address this in bash I'd opt for one of the awk solutions

Using any awk:
$ awk -F'>' 'NF>1{ close(out); out=$2".txt" } { print > out }' file1.txt


$ head *\|*
==> DGAT2|ENST00000604935.5.txt <==
>DGAT2|ENST00000604935.5
AGAAAGGCCGGGCGCGGCGAGGCTGGGCGCTGGGCGGCTGCGGCGCGCGGTGCGCGGTGC
GTAGTCTGGAGCTATGGTGGTGGTGGCAGCCGCGCCGAACCCGGCCGACGGGACCCCTAA
AGTTCTGCTTCTGTCGGGGCAGCCCGCCTCCGCCGCCGGAGCCCCGGCCGGCCAGGCCCT
GCCGCTCATGGTGCCAGCCCAGAGAGGGGCCAGCCCGGAGGCAGCGAGCGGGGGGCTGCC
CCAGGCGCGCAAGCGACAGCGCCTCACGCACCTGAGCCCCGAGGAGAAGGCGCTGAGGAG
GTGGGCGAGGGGCCGGGGTCTGGGGCCAGATCTGAAGCCGGGACTAGGGACAGGGGCAGG

==> PDGFRB|ENST00000522466.1.txt <==
>PDGFRB|ENST00000522466.1
TCAGTCATCCTTTCCCTCTCTAGCCCCCTACCCTATCCCCAAGCTGAAGTGCTAGTGGCT
GGTGGTGACTTCCCCAGACCTAAGCCAATCTCTCTCTACCAGTGTCATCCATCAACGTCT
CTGTGAACGCAGTGCAGACTGTGGTCCGCCAGGGTGAGAACATCACCCTCATGTGCATTG
TGATCGGGAATGAGGTGGTCAACTTCGAGTGGACATACCCCCGCAAAGAAGTAATGTGGG
GCCAGGCAGGGGTCGGAGGAGGGGCCAGGAACGGGTGGATATCTGGCTTGCAGGCTGATT
TCTCCCCGGCCCCTCCTGATTTGGGGGGCCTGCCCAACCTGTTGCTGCAGAGTGGGCGGC
TGGTGGAGCCGGTGACTGACTTCCTCTTGGATATGCCTTACCACATCCGCTCCATC


Did you consider awk for this task?
awk -F'\n' -v RS='>' '
    FNR > 1 {
      outFile = $1 ".txt";
      printf("%s", RS $0) > outFile;
      close(outFile);
    }
' file1.txt

The idea is to split the input file in >-delimited records; the first line of each record being the "header" of the sequence without its leading >.
Now, the very first record of the file is expected to be empty (or containing comments), so you skip it using the condition FNR > 1

ASIDE
Not that it is wrong, but do you really want to keep the | in the filenames?

the | is unavoidable currently. I was thinking to remove it later

Well, it simple enough to replace it with an _ or whatever in the awk code: gsub(/\|/, "_", outFile)

awk is the better way to do this, but if you're going to try using a while/read loop, you probably want to structure it like:
while read line; do f=${line#>}; 
    if ! test "$f" = "$line"; then exec > $f.txt; fi; 
    printf '%s\n' "$line"; 
done < input

Note that if you do that in an interactive terminal, you'll want to either run it in a subshell or followup with exec > /dev/tty or similar.
